# Where does Grail's errors property come from?

Tags: validation, grails, grails-2.0

Grails has a bug with regards to databinding in that it throws a cast exception when you're dealing with bad numerical input. JIRA: http://jira.grails.org/browse/GRAILS-6766

To fix this I've written the following code to manually handle the numerical input on the POGO class `Foo` located in `src/groovy`

```
void setPrice(String priceStr)
{
    this.priceString = priceStr

    // Remove $ and , 
    priceStr = priceStr.trim().replaceAll(java.util.regex.Matcher.quoteReplacement('$'),'').replaceAll(',','')

    if (!priceStr.isDouble()) {
        errors.reject(
            'trade.price.invalidformat',
            [priceString] as Object[],
            'Price:[{0}] is an invalid price.')

        errors.rejectValue(
            'price',
            'trade.price.invalidformat')
    } else {
        this.price = priceStr.toDouble();
    }
}
```

The following throws a null reference exception on the `errors.reject()` line.

```
foo.price = "asdf" // throws null reference on errors.reject()
foo.validate()
```

However, I can say:

```
foo.validate()
foo.price = "asdf" // no Null exception
foo.hasErrors() // false
foo.validate()
foo.hasErrors() // true
```

Where does errors come from when `validate()` is called?
Is there a way to add the `errors` property without calling `validate()` first?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I can't exactly tell you why, but you need to call `getErrors()` explicitly instead of accessing it as `errors` like a property. For some reason, Groovy isn't calling the method for it. So change the `reject` lines in `setPrice()` to

```
getErrors().reject(
        'trade.price.invalidformat',
        [priceString] as Object[],
        'Price:[{0}] is an invalid price.')

getErrors().rejectValue(
        'price',
        'trade.price.invalidformat')
```

That is the easiest way to make sure the `Errors` object exists in your method. You can [check out the code](https://github.com/grails/grails-core/blob/master/grails-plugin-domain-class/src/main/groovy/org/codehaus/groovy/grails/plugins/DomainClassGrailsPlugin.groovy#L224) that adds the validation related methods to your domain class.

Answer (score 5):

The AST transformation handling `@Validateable` [augments the class with, among other things](https://github.com/grails/grails-core/blob/master/grails-core/src/main/groovy/org/codehaus/groovy/grails/compiler/injection/ASTValidationErrorsHelper.java)

- a field named `errors`
- public methods `getErrors`, `setErrors`, `clearErrors` and `hasErrors`

The `getErrors` method lazily sets the `errors` field if it hasn't yet been set.  So it looks like what's happening is that accesses to `errors` within the same class are treated as field accesses rather than Java Bean property accesses, and bypassing the lazy initialization.

So the fix appears to be to use `getErrors()` instead of just `errors`.

Comment: Hrm, I must have glossed over the POGO bit and assumed it was a domain class

Comment: @doelleri I think the same transform applies to domain classes too, the code you linked to only fires for those domain classes that weren't enhanced at compile time (which can happen for dev mode auto-recompiles).  You deserve the accept, I was just addressing your "I can't exactly tell you why" :-)

Answer (score 2):

The errors are add to your validateable classes (domain classes and classes that have the annotation `@Validateable`) dinamically.

Allowing the developer to set a String instead of a number doesn't seem a good way to go. Also, your validation will work only for that particular class.

I think that a better approach is to register a custom property editor for numbers. Here's [a example](http://www.dataworks-inc.com/site/blog/handling-date-parameters-in-grails) with dates, that enable the transform of `String` (comming from the form) to `Date` with a format like dd/MM/yyyy. The idea is the same, as you will enforce that your number is parseable (eg. `Integer.parseInt()` will throw exception).

In your domain class, use the numeric type instead of String, so by code developers will not be allowed to store not number values.